# Trying to access a different Excel Sheet within a Match function within an Address function within an Indirect function

Tags: excel

So here's what I'm trying to do, all nested together.

I'm trying to Match one string in the sheet that this command is in a cell in, comparing it to a range of strings in a different sheet (for example, in the main sheet, I have a value 1337 in cell I1670, and I'm trying to find '1337' in a different sheet, known as 'Sheet1'). That returns to me what Row the matching cell is. This function is:

```
=MATCH(I1670, Sheet1!G:G, 0)
```

Then, since in know that in the other sheet, the range is in Column G (Numerically, column 7), I'm trying to get the exact address of that using the Address function:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(I1670, Sheet1!G:G, 0), 7))
```

Then, I'm trying to get the value within that Cell, so I use the Indirect function:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(I1670, Sheet1!G:G, 0), 7))
```

I know this has problems. For starters, I'm trying to access the cell in another sheet, but Indirect, to my knowledge, would probably be looking for the resulting address in the current Sheet, not Sheet1. I'm not sure how to format it within this function to have it look in Sheet1.

When I just do `=ADDRESS(MATCH(I1670, Sheet1!G:G, 0),7)`, I get $G$6383, which is in fact the cell I want, Cell G6383, it's just that I don't know how to extract the info in it.

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what direction to look for, thanks! I tried looking and could not find a similar question, but it might be because I'm a huge Excel novice. I apologize if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(I1670, Sheet1!G:G, 0),7,,,"Sheet1"))
```

`ADDRESS` has an optional input for a sheet reference. If it's omitted the function will refer to the sheet that it is on [Source](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ADDRESS-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89)

Comment: Cannot believe I missed that when looking up the Address function. It works perfectly. Thank you so much for helping!